# Speed UP UPDATE process in Sqlite3 table

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am receiving .xlsx file and need to update Sqlite3 table, code below works but its kind a slow and have feeling that I am doing something wrong. Kindly asking for an advice how to speed up UPDATE process?
Thanks in advance.
(step 1)First using regex to split data into 3 Data-Frames
(step 2)Cleaning the data ("After cleaning have two columns loc and date") and creating dictionary
(step 3)Update Sqlite3 table while iterating thru dictionary in double four loop

Sqlite3 table:

```
# CREATE TABLE "m" (
#   "index" INTEGER,
#   "loc"   TEXT,
#   "1" REAL,
#   "2" REAL,
#   "3" REAL,
#   "4" REAL,
#   "5" REAL,
#   "6" REAL,
#   "7" REAL,
#   "8" REAL,
#   "9" REAL,
#   "10"    REAL,
#   "11"    REAL,
#   "12"    REAL,
#   "13"    REAL,
#   "14"    REAL,
#   "15"    REAL,
#   "16"    REAL,
#   "17"    REAL,
#   "18"    REAL,
#   "19"    REAL,
#   "20"    REAL,
#   "21"    REAL,
#   "22"    REAL,
#   "23"    REAL,
#   "24"    REAL,
#   "25"    REAL,
#   "26"    REAL,
#   "27"    REAL,
#   "28"    REAL,
#   "29"    REAL,
#   "30"    REAL,
#   "31"    REAL,
#   "32"    REAL,
#   "33"    REAL,
#   "34"    REAL,
#   "35"    REAL,
#   "36"    REAL,
#   "37"    REAL,
#   "38"    REAL,
#   "39"    REAL,
#   "40"    REAL,
#   "41"    REAL,
#   "42"    REAL,
#   "43"    REAL,
#   "44"    REAL,
#   "45"    REAL,
#   "46"    REAL,
#   "47"    REAL,
#   "48"    REAL,
#   "49"    REAL,
#   "50"    REAL,
#   "51"    REAL,
#   "52"    REAL,
#   "Type"  TEXT
# )
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

def clean(data):
    df = data[['loc', 'date']].reset_index(drop = True)#Filtering columns that i need
    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week #Change column values to weeks
    return df
    
def update_cycle_counting(df):
    #Regex to filter data
    m = df[df['loc'].str.contains('A-[a-zA-Z]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}.\d{2}|E[a-zA-Z]\d{3}-\d{4}|M[a-zA-Z]\d{3}-\d{4}|SAFE\d*')]
    j1 = df[df['loc'].str.contains('C-[a-zA-Z]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}.\d{2}')]
    j2 = df[df['loc'].str.contains('B-[a-zA-Z]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}.\d{2}')]
    #Assign cleaned data to new variables
    m = clean(m)
    j1 = clean(j1)
    j2 = clean(j2)
    #Creating dictionary to loop thru
    wh = {'m':m, 'j1':j1, 'j2':j2}
    #Create path and connect to database
    path ='count.db'
    conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
    #Loop table names == dict.keys
    for k,v in wh.items():
        #Updating rows
        for i, row in v.iterrows():
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(f'UPDATE {k} SET "{row[1]}"= 1 WHERE "loc" = "{row[0]}";')
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: do not start transaction in each loop, try change it to 1. start transaction, 2. execute loop, 3. commit transaction

Answer (score 1):

Just create the cursor 1 time and commit less often to improve performance.
In this case we can commit all column updates at each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

def clean(data):
    df = data[['loc', 'date']].reset_index(drop = True)#Filtering columns that i need
    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week #Change column values to weeks
    return df
    
def update_cycle_counting(df):
    #Regex to filter data
    m = df[df['loc'].str.contains('A-[a-zA-Z]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}.\d{2}|E[a-zA-Z]\d{3}-\d{4}|M[a-zA-Z]\d{3}-\d{4}|SAFE\d*')]
    j1 = df[df['loc'].str.contains('C-[a-zA-Z]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}.\d{2}')]
    j2 = df[df['loc'].str.contains('B-[a-zA-Z]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}.\d{2}')]
    #Assign cleaned data to new variables
    m = clean(m)
    j1 = clean(j1)
    j2 = clean(j2)
    #Creating dictionary to loop thru
    wh = {'m':m, 'j1':j1, 'j2':j2}
    #Create path and connect to database
    path ='count.db'
    conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
    #Loop table names == dict.keys

    cur = conn.cursor()

    for k,v in wh.items():
        #Updating rows
        for i, row in v.iterrows():
            
            cur.execute(f'UPDATE {k} SET "{row[1]}"= 1 WHERE "loc" = "{row[0]}";')
        
        conn.commit()   # commit less often to improve performance
    
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```